# Conditionally format row based on 3 condiitons

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to conditionally color rows based on 3 conditions.

I'm looking for something equivalent to this: If (A2 !="") && (G2 !="" ) && (H2 == "")

If the cell in the row in column A isn't blank

AND

if the cell in the row in column G isn't blank

AND

If the cell in the row in column H IS blank.

I've tried a lot of If and AND statements and come up short.

What formula would give me the result I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=($A2<>"")*($G2<>"")*($H2="")
```

[image]